# Simple Conditional Probability in a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

> Buses arrive at a station in a Poisson process at a rate of 3 per hour.
>   Suppose 4 buses arrive in the first hour, what is the probability that a total of 6 buses arrive in the first two hours? 
>   Suppose 6 buses arrive in the first two hours, what is the probability that a 4 buses arrived in the first hour?

Just looking for a check on my reasoning here.

For the first question, if we are given that $X_1 = 4$ then the only way that $X_1 + X_2 = 6$ is to have $X_2 = 2$.  Thus, the probability is simply $P(X_2 = 2)$.

For the second question, there are 7 ways to have non-negative $X_1 + X_2 = 6$.  Only one involves $X_1 = 4$.  So here $P = 1/7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is correctly done, but the answer should be more explicit.

For the second question, let $A$ be the event $4$ buses arrive in the first hour, and $B$ the event there are $6$ buses in the $2$ hours. We want $\Pr(A\mid B)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$.

Compute. We have $\Pr(B)=e^{-6}\frac{6^6}{6!}$.

The probability of $A\cap B$ is the probability  of $4$ buses in the first hour and $2$ in the second. This is $e^{-3}\frac{3^4}{4!}e^{-3}\frac{3^2}{2!}$.

Divide. Our conditional probability is $\frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{3^2 3^4}{6^6}$, which is more nicely expressed as $\binom{6}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2^6}$.

A similar calculation shows that in general, the conditional distribution of the number of buses in the first $a$ hours, given that there were $n$ buses in the first $a+b$ hours, is *binomial*, parameters $p=\frac{a}{a+b}$, and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by $X_2$.

---

Part 1. In other words, you want two arrivals in in the interval $(1,2]$. Since disjoint blocks of time yield independent Poisson distributions, then you want
$$P(X_{(1,2)} = 2)$$
where $X_{(1,2)}\sim\text{Pois}(t\lambda = (2-1) 3)$.

Part 2. No. The quick way is to notice that you are dealing with a Binomial(6, 1/2). 
Otherwise, expand by Bayes' rule
$$P(X_{(0,1)} = 4|X_{(0,2)} = 6) = \frac{P(X_{(0,1)}=  4, X_{(0,2)} = 6)}{P(X_{(0,2)} = 6)}$$

Comment: Does the first part simply mean to use the Poisson general formula, substitute x = 2 and lambda = 3?

Comment: What is $x$ and what is $\lambda$? If you mean $e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x!$, then sure, that's the "formula". Also, please learn MathJax. You can find a short tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you see something in a post that you want to reproduce, just hit the "edit" button to examine the inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the answer 0.2240? Could you please check, it would be very helpful.

Comment: That's what I got. But be careful. It's more important to be able to understand the concept. Punching it into the calculator is the easy part. Practice more problems if you weren't able to get to this easily, or if you're still feeling shaky.

Comment: could you suggest some books or online resources to practice more problems related to poisson and binomial?

Comment: Sorry. I have no recommendation. Are _you_ using a textbook? Try yours. That's probably the best resource. Or ask your instructor for problems or books, if you have an instructor. You can also try searching questions on this site. Just look at the problem first, without looking at the answer, and then check the answer once you're done.

Comment: The kind of book I possess only contains simple, straightforward problems. I would like to try out more problems which need some thought rather than simply applying the formula.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I need one doubt to be cleared. I have solved this problem in the comment section. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737101/poisson-conditional-probability-on-pizza-order?rq=1

Comment: Sorry. I'm not interested in checking your work, because 1. I'm busy; 2. you didn't use MathJax, so it's kind of hard and discouraging to read; and 3. (this is the most important) **you should post your work as a new question**. Make a new post, copy the question to your new post, provide a link to the original question you found, **and show your work** (your thought process). Then someone else will be able to help you. The comments are not designed for extended discussions.

Comment: Also, you can check a user's profile to see when the last time they visited was. [Andre](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%c3%a9-nicolas), the person you asked, hasn't visited since Oct. 4, 2016. So he's unlikely to respond any time soon. Also, **please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)**. It will make your work easier to read and people will be more likely to help. Lastly, it can't be binomial since you are not given that exactly $n$ arrivals occurred in that hour. The OP's answer is correct.